# Find the limit or explain why it doesn't exist

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I'm having trouble starting this problem. I don't understand how I can make the limit apply when it's written with $x$ and $y$.

$$\lim_{z \to (1-i)} (x+i(2x+y))$$

If I change $z$ to $(x+iy) \to (1-i)$, then I can substitute it for the $x+iy$ in the expanded form of the problem:

$$\lim_{z \to (1-i)} (x+iy+2xi) = (1-i+2xi)$$

But then what happens to the $2xi$?

Comment: $x\to 1$, $y\to -1$.

Comment: is z= x + i y ?

Comment: @user48672 I think that's an assumption I can make, yea. The problem doesn't say otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\lim_{z \to (1-i)} (z+2 Re(z) i) = 1-i+2 i Re(z) =1 -i + 2 i = 1+i 
$

Comment: Arg I was close! I was thinking of something similar while I was waiting. This makes sense. Thanks a bunch!